# Java класс в Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, java

Необходимо выполнять некоторую обработку данных до записи в таблицы. Создал триггер, попробовал на простеньком Java классе - все работает. Но когда загружал "боевой" класс возникли трудности.

Класс:

```
...
byte[] initialBytesArray = bigIntegerID.toByteArray();
ArrayList<Byte> bytesList = new ArrayList<>();
for (byte b : initialBytesArray) {
    bytesList.add(new Byte(b));
}
...
```

Ругается следующим образом:

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-29536: неверно сформирован источник: Encountered ">" at line

То есть ему не нравится `ArrayList<Byte>` а без него обойтись ну никак. Есть какое-то решение таких проблем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня 2 варианта:

1. Oarcle не поддерживает фишки седьмой Java, поэтому нужно писать `ArrayList<Byte> bytesList = new ArrayList<Byte>();`, т. е. полностью объявление generic-а.
2. Oracle не поддерживает фишки пятой Java, поэтому использовать generic-и вообще не нужно. В этом случае код будет выглядеть как `ArrayList bytesList = new ArrayList();`, а при извлечении элементов из `bytesList` придётся вручную кастовать их в `Byte`.

Comment: Благодарю! Сработал 1 вариант.